# From Ubuntu kvm I am unable to connect to synology Disk Station iSCSI target

Tags: kvm, libvirt, iscsi, virsh

My goal is to create a storage pool for KVM with an iSCSI target hosted in Synology Disk Station.

I've created an iSCSI target in Synology Disk Station, with no Chap.
I am able to connect to and use this target in ESXI, but I am unable to do the same in KVM.

To connect to it in ESXI I had to create add a Host in Synology Disk Station and provided the initiator iqn.

I attempted to add a Host in Synology Disk Station for KVM but I cannot find any wait to get the KVM initiator iqn. I'm not sure if the Host is needed or not.

Using [Cockpit](https://github.com/cockpit-project/cockpit-machines) I've attempted to create a storage pool.

I enter the correct host and iqn and create the pool, then I click activate. Shortly after I get the error `method call Create timed out`.

The target is query-able using `sudo isnsadm --list nodes --local` but that is the most I've been able to achieve.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The address connecting with needs to match iSCSI network bindings.

I found in my synology I was only binding to 3/4 nics and the 4th is the one I was attempting to connect on.